# Layout's onMesure bizarre behaviour

Tags: android

in my application there is square customizable tactile area.

User can customize position (left top, center bottom, ...) and size in percentage of parent's size.

xml view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="fr.tactiledialog.TestBoxActivity">

    <fr.tactiledialog.layout.SquareLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_tactile_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Custom Square layout' onMeasue:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    size = (width > height ? height : width) * getPercentageSizeFromPreferences() / 100;

    Log.e("DIALOG", width + " ~ " + height + " = " +  size);

    setMeasuredDimension(size, size); // to make it square
}
```

the problem is that this method is called multiple times (four times to be precise) with these values:

```
E/DIALOG: 984 ~ 1677 = 541
E/DIALOG: 541 ~ 1581 = 297
E/DIALOG: 984 ~ 1677 = 541
E/DIALOG: 541 ~ 1581 = 297
```

I'm not experienced Android developer so I can't figure out the logic and the solution. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably what is happening is a parent layout is getting resized, so the square layout is also getting resized.

Comment: It happens immediately after activity is loaded.